# Angular 4 Async pipe with new Observable and ng-template doesn't work

Tags: angular, observable, ng-template

I'm trying to display a list of rooms using Angular 4 async pipe and an Observable created with `new Observable()`.

I have a RoomService defined like this:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { DatabaseService } from '../core/database.service';
import { Room } from './room';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
  private store: any;

  constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {
    this.store = this.db.store('rooms');
  }

  getRooms(query: any = {}): Observable<Room[]> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.store.find(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          observer.error(error);
        } else {
          const rooms = results.map(room => {
            return new Room(room.building, room.number, room._id);
          });
          observer.next(rooms);
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
   });
  }
}
```

and a RoomListComponent defined like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Room } from '../room';
import { RoomService } from '../room.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-room-list',
  templateUrl: './room-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./room-list.component.scss']
})
export class RoomListComponent implements OnInit {
  rooms$: Observable<Room[]>;

  constructor(private roomService: RoomService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rooms$ = this.roomService.getRooms();
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to display rooms like this:

```html
<h1>Rooms</h1>
<div *ngIf="$rooms | async as rooms; else loading">
  <div *ngFor="let room of rooms">
    {{ room.number }}
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

But it's not working. The view keep showing Loading... Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think it can be a syntax error.
It should be <div *ngIf="rooms$ | async as rooms; else loading"> on the template.

Comment: You shouldn't change your question after it has been answered. It ruins the context of the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call method in template because it will be returning new observable every change detection tick.

You could try this:

```typescript
rooms$: Observable<Room[]>;

constructor(private roomService: RoomService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.rooms$ = this.roomService.getRooms()
}
```

**view.html**

```typescript
<div *ngIf="rooms$ | async as rooms; else loading">
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/G0cpogQ7bEI0eN4yV3wl?p=preview)**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the code as you suggested but it's still not working, the view keep showing Loading...

Comment: Then i want to see a reproduction. Do you have any github repo to reproduce it?

Comment: Try to set `debugger` front of `observer.next(rooms);`

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/valerymelou/pharaoh-bills. Checkout the branch feature/rooms

Comment: Because you don't have any entry in your database. And even if the service returns `[]` array it should render the empty `<ul></ul>` tag. It seems like async doesn't automatically subscribe to the observer as it's supposed to.

Comment: I removed my code. It renders empty `ul` tag http://take.ms/l3kca Did you try your repo? Maybe you have problem with dependencies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145039/discussion-between-valery-melou-and-yurzui).

Comment: Okay I'll try that and let you know about the result.

Comment: I removed my node_modules folder and reinstalled it. Everything is working as expected. Thanks for your help.